# Xstartup file for Gnome 3 session on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, gnome3, vnc

Is it possible to have a TurboVNC session, or indeed and vnc server session, to a Ubuntu 16.04 system display a desktop the same as what one gets when logging in locally, with the Activities bar and so on? I can't find examples of this. My effort so far produced the following xstartup file, but although it works, I only get the old Applications menu, not the more recent Gnome 3 desktop.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Uncomment the following two lines for normal desktop:
unset SESSION_MANAGER
unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS

[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey

gnome-session --session=ubuntu &
gnome-shell &
gnome-panel &
gnome-settings-daemon &
metacity &
nautilus &
gnome-terminal &
```

What am I missing?